# Applescript combining file paths

Tags: applescript, posix, filepath

I am using applescript with QuarkXpress and want to save a file into eps format. The saving is perfectly fine, except for the location of the saved file. Here's the relevant code:

```
set newFileName to "e.eps"
set newFilePath to "/Users/user123"
        save page 1 in (newFilePath & newFilePath) EPS format EPSFormat EPS data EPSData scale EPSScale without transparent page
```

This saved the file in the QuarkXpress application folder with the name "/Users/user123/e.eps".
How can i avoid this? Thanks

Comment: where do you want to save it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, because of AppleScript's origins during the pre-Mac OS X days, it doesn't use POSIX paths by default. You can either specify the path using AppleScript's native format (`Hard Drive Name:Users:user123:e.eps`) or by translating a POSIX path into an AppleScript path using `(POSIX file "/Users/user123/") & "e.eps"`.

Answer (score 0):

it just depends where you want to put it.

```
set dt to path to desktop
set newFileName to "e.eps"
set newFilePath to "" & dt & newFileName

save page 1 in (newFilePath) EPS format EPSFormat EPS data EPSData scale EPSScale without transparent page
```

maybe the desktop ?